# AWS Amplify - No option for container based hosting

Tags: next.js, amazon-ecs, aws-amplify, aws-fargate, aws-amplify-cli

I'm trying to set up an Next.js app on Amplify with container-based hosting on Fargate, but when I run `amplify add hosting`, the only two options I get are `Amplify Console` and `CloudFront + S3`.

[image]

I've already configured the project to enable container-based deployments, but I'm just not presented with the option to do so

[image]

Amplify CLI version is v4.41.2 and the `container-hosting` plugin is correctly listed in the active plugins

[image]

Region is `eu-west-1`, the CLI is configured and I've gone through all the steps more than once.

```
amplify init
amplify configure project
amplify add hosting
```

Are there any prerequisites, something I missed or don't know of? I can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this video it's only available in US East 1 currently.

https://youtu.be/rA5l82vypXc

Answer (score 2):

Here's the limitation they have mentioned in their docs: [https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/containers/#:~:text=Hosting%20with%20Fargate%20in%20Amplify%20is%20only%20available%20in%20US%2DEast%2D1%20at%20this%20time](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/containers/#:%7E:text=Hosting%20with%20Fargate%20in%20Amplify%20is%20only%20available%20in%20US%2DEast%2D1%20at%20this%20time)

> Hosting with Fargate in Amplify is only available in US-East-1 at this
> time

So the best solution would be to change the region of your project itself, if possible. Otherwise, use ECS and build your CI/CD pipeline manually (CodePipeline).